# Remove duplicate item in a list - Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, duplicates

I have a list where users can dynamically add items.
The list looks like this :

```
 [{author: Tsubasa Yamaguchi, created: 24 Juin 2017, total_chapter: 34, genre: seinen, pic: https://www.nautiljon.com/images/more/03/72/278427.jpg, title: Blue Period}, {author: Tsubasa Yamaguchi, created: 24 Juin 2017, total_chapter: 34, genre: seinen, pic: https://www.nautiljon.com/images/more/03/72/278427.jpg, title: Blue Period}]
```

I don't want any duplicates in this list because I display items in a listView.
I've tried the method of `list.toSet().toList()` but for some reason, I have the same result.
I think it's because of the format or my items '`{}`'.

Any suggestion?

This is how I obtain my list :

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
List favMangasListTitle = [];
List detailledMangaList = [];
String title = '';
String read_chapter = '';
Future<List> getFavMangas() async {
  var value = await firestore.collection("users/${user.uid}/fav_mangas").get();
  final favMangasGetter = value.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  favMangasListTitle.clear();
  detailledMangaList.clear();
  for (var i in favMangasGetter) {
    title = i['title'];
    read_chapter = i['read_chapter'];
    favMangasListTitle.add(title);
  }

  await Future.forEach(favMangasListTitle, (i) async {
    final mangas =
        await firestore.collection('mangas').where('title', isEqualTo: i).get();
    final receivedMangaDetailled =
        mangas.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    detailledMangaList.addAll(receivedMangaDetailled);
  });

  var test = detailledMangaList.toSet().toList();
  print(test);

  return detailledMangaList;
}
```

Comment: you want elements with the same author to not be duplicated ?

Comment: No, I want the elements with the same title to not be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the comment, while the `title` is being prioritized, you can create a set of titles and then create a unique map.

```dart
     final data = [...yourData]
     final titles = data.map((e) => e["title"]).toSet();

      final result = [];
      for (final title in titles) {
        final item = data.firstWhere((element) =>
            element["title"] == title); // include `orElse` if needed
        result.add(item);
      }
      print(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package and try this and the `data` is your list:

```
var grouped = groupBy(data, (Map value) => value['title']);

var result = grouped.entries.map((e) => e.value.first).toList();
print("result = $result");
```

first you grouped your itmes in your list by their `title` and then in second line we chose the first item in each group and that gives us a list without any duplicate with `name`.

Comment: I upvote your answer because it can be useful to other if they want to try with package. For me, I try to limit the usage of package when I can. But thank for your time !